# Can't remove duplicates in array

Tags: php, duplicates

I've got 2 files and turn them to an array and then merge them with:

```
$array1  = file('http://domain.com/1.txt');
$array2  = file('http://domain.com/2.txt');
$arraysmerged = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r ($array1);echo '<br>';
print_r ($array2);echo '<br>';
print_r ($arraysmerged);echo '<br><br><br>';
```

This returns:

```
Array ( [0] => ﻿green [1] => red [2] => green [3] => yellow ) 
Array ( [0] => ﻿orange [1] => blue ) 
Array ( [0] => ﻿green [1] => red [2] => green [3] => yellow [4] => ﻿orange [5] => blue )
```

Though, I want to remove duplicates, in this case "green" should only occur 1 time.
I've searched around and tried out all different approaches, but they all turn out the same or turn out to give an array. At the moment I have these:

```
$arraysnodups = array_unique($arraysmerged);
$arraysnodups2= array_values(array_unique($arraysmerged));
$arraysnodups3 = array_unique(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));
print_r ($arraysnodups);echo '<br>';
print_r ($arraysnodups2);echo '<br>';
print_r( $arraysnodups3);;echo '<br>';
```

But they all return:

```
Array ( [0] => ﻿green [1] => red [2] => green [3] => yellow [4] => ﻿orange [5] => blue ) 
Array ( [0] => ﻿green [1] => red [2] => green [3] => yellow [4] => ﻿orange [5] => blue ) 
Array ( [0] => ﻿green [1] => red [2] => green [3] => yellow [4] => ﻿orange [5] => blue )
```

So dups are not removed...

I hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works here fine. There must be some differences between your green and your other green. Please replace `print_r` by `var_export` and post the result.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a `\n` or `\r\n` combo difference or other whitespace problem.  Try:

```
$arraysmerged = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$arraysmerged = array_map('trim', $arraysmerged);
$arraysnodups = array_unique($arraysmerged);
```

Comment: can you show an working example with any one of the above array

Comment: I just tried this but the result is the same as it didn't remove any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works.
A combination of the above answer (the trimming) + writing it to another text file of which I was sure there was no hidden block character in the beginning. Thanks.